# Adding icon to Calculated Tableau Field

Tags: tableau-desktop

I am trying to add a small green arrow to a calculated field in Tableau. I cannot figure out for the life of me what to do. I have some images in my Tableau Repository, but the way my trainer is showing us is she is literally copy and pasting an image and it appears in the calculated field dialog box. I have tried to copy an image and paste it with no luck. Does anyone know how to do this? My trainer in the videos just does it like magic with no explanation of how to do it and it drives me insane. The code is very simple as I just want a green up arrow next to the growth percentage if its positive.

```
IF [Growth Percentage Profit] > 0
THEN "*green up arrow here*"
END
```

Answer (score 2):

I exactly don't know how you are trying to do so.

but can get steps to do this from this link below.
may it could help you.

https://www.google.com/search?q=tableau+up+arrow+green&rlz=1C1UEAD_enPK957PK957&sxsrf=ALiCzsbLWY6J2Zh1jYWOX6_jq310QuQYow:1669030745991&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjRi--FmL_7AhW5nP0HHbHsANEQ_AUoA3oECAEQBQ&biw=960&bih=936&dpr=1#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:0c41f2fc,vid:RSV3cm_mTHw